# Xamarin Loop (Thread) in Foreground Service not continue when device is unplugged

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, foreground-service

Hi i've a problem getting location each 1-5 minutes with a Foreground Service, when I unplug the device and turn off the screen, the thread stops but the service notification is visible all time,
how can i prevent this?

i was reading about to use AlarmManager (is a real solution), how can i do it ? or should only foreground service do it  by self

this is my code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text.Format;
using Invima.VehiculosApp.ViewModels;
using Java.Util;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Invima.VehiculosApp
{
    [Service(Label = "LocationUpdatesService", Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.Antss.InvimaVehiculos.Service" })]
    public class LocationService : Service
    {
        IBinder Binder;
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return Binder;
        }

        public const int ServiceRunningNotifID = 9000;

        Ruta ruta;
        Thread hiloUbicacion;

        private System.Timers.Timer timer;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            Notification notif = DependencyService.Get<INotification>().ReturnNotif();
            StartForeground(ServiceRunningNotifID, notif);

            _ = TomarUbicaciones();

            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            string rutaStr = intent.GetStringExtra("ruta");

            this.ruta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ruta>(rutaStr);

            var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            // i tried this but ... the same problem
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
            timer.Elapsed += async (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                using (HttpClient cl = new HttpClient())
                {
                    await cl.GetAsync("https://webhook.site/a718fef4-769b-4871-87a8-ec1ccd83fc50");
                }
            };
            timer.Start();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }


        public int TomarUbicaciones()
        {
            hiloUbicacion = new Thread(TomarUbicacionAsync);
            hiloUbicacion.Start();
            return 1;
        }

        int contador = 0;
        public async void TomarUbicacionAsync()
        {

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
                    var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);


                    if (location != null && ruta != null)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");

                        App.BD.RutaUbicacion.Add(new RutaUbicacion
                        {
                            Fecha = DateTime.Now,
                            IdRuta = ruta.IdRuta,
                            Latitud = (decimal)location.Latitude,
                            Longitud = (decimal)location.Longitude,
                            Altitud = (decimal)location.Altitude
                        });

                        App.BD.SaveChanges();

                        App.Sincronizar();
                    }


                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShortAlert("Done!");
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }


                Thread.Sleep(60000);  // each minute
            }
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            try
            {
                hiloUbicacion.Abort();
            }
            catch { }
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        public override bool StopService(Intent name)
        {
            try
            {
                hiloUbicacion.Abort();
            }
            catch { }
            return base.StopService(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unplugging it while debugging?

Comment: when device is charging works too, i understand, android sleep my thread to save battery, but i created the foreground service to do it, but it no prevent to android sleep my thread

Comment: The only necessary thing for the foreground service is a Notification (with a NotificationChannel on Android O and up) and a call to StartForeground. This should keep the App alive. Why your thread dies I don't know. Are OnDestroy or StopService called for some reason? Is there any exception thrown anywhere? Also for the OnBind, it is ok to return null if you are not binding to the Service in your App.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Sorry, I did not notice that. I wanted to post in comment before.

Comment: In Android, starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), an Android application no longer have the ability to run freely in the background. You could check the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80 You could try to restart the service once it been finished by a BroadcastReceiver. https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android